# Get the list of items in SharePoint API which starts with "_"

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

***API Call:** "https://tponline.sharepoint.com/sites/tc-g-learning/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents - Learning Centre')/items?$select=_DisplayName,Title,Modified_x0020_By"*

When only "Title" or "Modified_x0020_By" is filtered, then the result is returned where as if we pass _DisplayName it says error. But when we call API to get list of all item names using 'https://tponline.sharepoint.com/sites/tc-g-learning/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(''Documents - Learning Centre'')/Fields?$select=Title,InternalName' then we can see _DisplayName in return.

```
"{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The field or property '_DisplayName' does not exist."
        }
    }
}"
```

**Note:** Tried with some of other items beginning with "_" then we get same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can first hit the API URL for getting the fields only.

URL : [https://tponline.sharepoint.com/sites/tc-g-learning/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents%20-%20Learning%20Centre')/Fields](https://tponline.sharepoint.com/sites/tc-g-learning/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(%27Documents%20-%20Learning%20Centre%27)/Fields)

Once you open this, you will see the internal name that is used by API for all the fields in the list.

I too had similar problem where my column name was **_Status** and the internal name was **OData__Status**
Hope that helps !!!